# Can't connect Wifi devices to router when wired Ethernet computer is connected

Tags: router, network-interface

I have a arch desktop with samba and ssh configured connected to a WiFi router/ADSL2 modem via ethernet.

I was not able to connect any of my mobile devices (phones and tablet) or my netbook (running windows 7 basic) to the WiFi router suddenly a few weeks back. The issue resolved when I removed the PC Ethernet cable from the router (when I disconnected the PC from router).

My router is D-Link DSL 2730 U

1. On logging into another user (not main user) everything works fine.
2. Nothing changes when I stopped samba and ssh services. Infact these services which are configured as root, start before the login
3. I use console without any gui to login. I `startx` manually after logging in. This problem does not occur on logging in. It starts only when I startx
4. On using wireshark to capture traffic on the ethernet port, this line keeps repeating:

   ```
   0.007238000 192.168.1.100   224.0.0.56  UDP 1334    Source port: 38854  Destination port: 46198
   ```

I have no idea what to do beyond this. The internet works fine when logged into main user. However other devices are not able to connect.

Please tell me how to resolve this and what is happening.

Comment: 224.0.0.0/24 are multicast addresses (I do not know how this applies to your case). I am not a network expert, but if the only settings in the modem are your ISP's password, WiFi password and a couple of Firewall rules, I'd reset it.  Or, if I see something in NAT or firewall/port forwarding rules relevant to the ports 1334, 38854, 46198 I'd remove it for starters.

Comment: @pidosaurus I found the answer. Please look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys I found out what happened.

I ran `netstat -aup` which shows all the UDP ports and the processes attached to it.

The options:

```
a - listen to all sockets (when combined with u listens only to UDP sockets)
u - listen to udp ports 
p - lists the processes attached to the ports
```

I found out that the process attached to `port 38854` was `pulseaudio`. On killing pulseaudio the problem resolved.

I then installed `paprefs` and disabled multicast/RTP sender and receiver and on restarting `pulseaudio` the problem did not persist.

There is a bugreport here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44777